# Modify beamer template to avoid section header being hidden by logos

Tags: beamer, header-footer

I'm using beamer theme AnnArbor and the `textpos` package to put an institutional logo on the upper right corner of both ordinary pages and section title pages. The problem is that, when I write

```
\section{Corpus}\frame{\sectionpage}
```

the logo is so wide that it covers part of my section header, here, for example, on the section title page:

[image]

And here on a subsequent ordinary page:

[image]

How can I push the section header to the left, by the same amount on all slides, so that the entire section title is visible ?

(I know that by writing

```
\section[Contexte\hbox to 0.7cm{}]{Corpus}\frame{\sectionpage}
```

I get the desired effect

[image]

but this is not an elegant solution since I will have to constantly add code to `\section` command arguments and if I want to use the same slides with a logo of different width, I will have to correct all `\section` commands, not very elegant. It would be better to do it once and for all in the preamble of the document, if this is possible…)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could redefine the `headline` template in order to get the following output:

[image]

The `AnnArbor` theme loads the `infolines` outer theme. Looking at the file `beamerouterthemeinfolines.sty`, we can find the following definition of the `headline` template

```
\defbeamertemplate*{headline}{infolines theme}
{%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.65ex,dp=1.5ex,right]{section in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\insertsectionhead\hspace*{2ex}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.65ex,dp=1.5ex,left]{subsection in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\hspace*{2ex}\insertsubsectionhead
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
```

that results in two equally wide boxes that house the section and subsection titles. In the following MWE, I changed the width arguments from `wd=.5\paperwidth` to `wd=.25\paperwidth` and `wd=.75\paperwidth`. Feel free to further adjust these to your needs. This headline  template will also still print subsection titles in the header. If you want to avoid that, as well, remove the line `\usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\hspace*{2ex}\insertsubsectionhead`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{AnnArbor}
\usecolortheme{beaver}

\defbeamertemplate*{headline}{my infolines theme}
{%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.25\paperwidth,ht=2.65ex,dp=1.5ex,right]{section in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\insertsectionhead\hspace*{2ex}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.75\paperwidth,ht=2.65ex,dp=1.5ex,left]{subsection in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\hspace*{2ex}\insertsubsectionhead
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}

\begin{document}
\section{section}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{frame title}
contents
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

---

If you on the other hand want to keep the equally wide colored backgrounds and just want to move the section title a bit to the right, adjust the value of the first `\hspace*` command.

Something like

```
\defbeamertemplate*{headline}{my infolines theme}
{%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.65ex,dp=1.5ex,right]{section in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\insertsectionhead\hspace*{20ex}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.65ex,dp=1.5ex,left]{subsection in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\hspace*{2ex}\insertsubsectionhead
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
```

will result in:

[image]

---

If you instead want to get a left aligned instead of right aligned section title in the frame header, try something like

```
\defbeamertemplate*{headline}{my infolines theme}
{%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.65ex,dp=1.5ex,left]{section in head/foot}%
   \hspace*{2ex}\usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\insertsectionhead
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.65ex,dp=1.5ex,left]{subsection in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\hspace*{2ex}\insertsubsectionhead
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
```

to get:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, but it doesn't seem to work. I tried the second code (with the `\hspace*{20ex}`). I runs but has no effect.

Comment: How exactly did you try the second suggestion? Did you take the MWE from my answer and replace the entire `\defbeamertemplate` part with the second suggestion (this should definitely work and is how I produced the screenshot)  or did you try to incorporate my suggestion into your actual document? If the latter is the case, it is hard to tell what went wrong without a proper MWE that allows otehrs to reproduce the otuput you get.

Comment: OK, I found the error. It works great, thanks!